# Split query results in 2 div's

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have this php mysql query

```
<?php
  $product = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 6 ');
  $pro  = mysql_fetch_assoc($product);
?>
```

Now that query will return 6 products from database and what i want to do is echo 3 products inside a `<div>` and the other 3 products inside another `<div>` like this

```
<div class="first-3>
///Here i want to echo 3 products from the query from 1-3
   <?php echo $pro['title']; ?>
</div>

<div class="second-3>
///Here i want to echo the rest 3 products of the query from 4-6
   <?php echo $pro['title']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So where are you stuck, and what does this have to do with jquery or css?

Comment: Did you try anything? Even just hardcoding three array values in each div with echo statements should work ?

Comment: And what is the problem with using 2 loops ?

Comment: using 2 loops is Not Recommended for clean code @OrelEraki

Comment: Maybe there is some css or Jquery solution for this @JasonP

Comment: @YoussefSubehi, It's is recommended for this kind of code, for more elegent looking code it isn't.

Comment: @YoussefSubehi where did you get that idea? Two loops is what I would do for this. And of you're talking about recommended code, stop using **Mysql_***, it's depreciated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: No i didn't if you have something in your mind like code or startup help for that i would be happy to try it @adeneo

Comment: ok lets say 2 loops will do BUT should i have 2 query also ?

Comment: @YoussefSubehi No, why would you have 2 queries?

Comment: One loop is enough, just use a condition to output another div.

Comment: could you share me a code to do it with 2 loops @Styphon

Comment: guys im here cuz i want some help with code like share me a piece of code to start with it so could you please try to share me the code to get the idea about it

Comment: @YoussefSubehi patience, it takes time to write code. There are answers now, jeez.

Comment: Thanks a Lot @Styphon will be looking for it and chose the best thanks

Comment: @YoussefSubehi, I've shorten it and styled it, so it will be one loop and well read. update with the new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $num = 6;
    $product = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products LIMIT $num');

    $firstDiv = "";
    $secondDiv = "";
    $i = 0;
    while ($pro  = mysql_fetch_assoc($product)) {
        if ($i < ($num /2)) {
            $firstDiv .= $pro['title'];
        }
        else {
            $secondDiv .= $pro['title'];
        }
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

And:

```
<div class="first-3>
    <?php $firstDiv ?>
</div>

<div class="second-3>
    <?php $secondDiv ?>
</div>
```

Comment: aren't you missing an $i++ ?

Comment: @JoeDaniels, Indeed, after all this time.. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate and output the values.

```
<?php
    $product = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 6 ');
    $i = 1;

    echo '<div class="first-3">';

    while ( $pro  = mysql_fetch_assoc($product) ) {
        if ($i === 3) {
             echo '</div><div class="second-3">';
        }

        echo $pro['title'];
        $i++;
    }

    echo '</div>';

?>
```

Note that it's not safe to use `mysql_query`, you should be using `mysqli` or preferrably PDO.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_assoc is used to retrieve a row in the resultset.

Doc: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

A loop is required to iterate on each row.

A very simple example:

```
// Get a collection of 6 results
$products = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 6 ');


// iterate over the 6 results
$i=0;
echo '<div class="first-3>';
while ($pro = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)) {
    $i++;

    // Print an item
    echo $pro["title"];

    // If 3 items are printed end first div and start second div
    if($i==3){
        echo '</div><div class="second-3">';
    }

}
echo '</div>';

// Free the collection resources
mysql_free_result($products);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set up a counter to divide in groups of 3:

```
$count = 0;

while (...)
{
  // your code

  $count++;
  if ( ($count % 3) === 0 )
  {
    echo '</div><div class="...">';
  }
}
```

Please note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and you should switch to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

```
$product = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 6 ');
$results = array();
while($pro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product)) {
    $results[] = $pro;
}
echo '<div class="first-3">';
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo $results[$i]['title'];
}
echo '</div><div class="second-3">';
for($i = 3; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo $results[$i]['title'];
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you get the multiple of 3, ($k % 3 == 0) you will increment the flag variable, you can do then some conditions with the variable flag, i used here iterators because the hasNext() beauty.

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K0y8ds)

```
$pro = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$flag = 0;
$pro = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($pro));

foreach ($pro as $k => $v) {

    // if multiples 3
    if ($k % 3 == 0) {
        $flag++;

        if ($flag == 1) {
            echo '<div class="first-3" style="border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:10px;">';
        } else if ($flag == 2) {
            echo '</div>'; // Closes the first div
            echo '<div class="second-3" style="border:1px solid red">';
        }else{ // if you have more than 6
                echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    // insert Data
    echo $v . '<br/>';

    if (!$pro->hasNext())
        echo '</div>'; // if there is no more closes the div
}
```